# Whether the functions in _generic can use macro functions defined by define？

Tags: c

```
#define a printf("I am int type !!~\n");

#define b printf("I am double type !!~\n");

#define foo(x) _Generic(x, int : a, \
                          double : b)(x)

int main(){
    foo(123);  // foo_int(123) // I am int type !!~
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this give an error？and The compiler tells me: Should type ")"

When I change the function call in _Generic to one that is not defined by define, the compiler does not throw an error.

Comment: Think how it is going to be expanded. Step by step. Hint: First the `foo` will get expanded, and it will contain some invalid `_Generic` syntax from the `a` and `b` expansions: https://godbolt.org/z/sjxK9h1v8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Whether the functions in _generic can use macro functions defined by define?

The identifiers inside `_Generic` *will be expanded* before `_Generic` takes place. In that sense, you can use macros.

> Why does this give an error？

`foo(123);` *expands* to

```
_Generic(123, int : printf("I am int type !!~\n");, double : printf("I am double type !!~\n");)(123);
```

The `;` before `,` inside `_Generic` are just invalid, and the `(x)` after `_Generic(...)(123)` also doesn't make sense. The produced code is not following the syntax of C programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of the `_Generic` cases must be expressions (specifically an *assignment-expression*). `printf("I am int type !!~\n");` is a statement, not an expression.

When you remove the semicolon, it is an expression. Then `_Generic(x, int : a, double : b)` would be fine, but you have `(x)` after it. Why?

After processing of the `_Generic`, the expression is basically `printf("I am int type !!~\n")`. That is a complete function call. Putting `(x)` after it to make `printf("I am int type !!~\n")(x)` attempts to make another function call, but that does not work since `printf` returns an `int`, not a pointer to a function. Remove `(x)`.